# Deshabilitar un data list desde javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Desde una función, estoy condicionando que con un check se habilite o deshabilite un data list que tengo declarado en un archivo php.

El data list lleva de nombre `dlClient`:

Y en mi función estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$("#chkNewProspect").click(function()
    {
        var checked_status = this.checked;

        if (checked_status == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("dlClient").disabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("#dlClient").disabled = false;
        }
    });
```

Pero no logro se desactive dicho datalist. ¿Alguien ha tenido una experiencia similar?

```
<input list="dlClient" class='col-lg-12' style='height:35px' enabled> 
<?php datalistCliente("dlClient",1,2); ?> –
```

Este código esta en PHP y recupera un listado, funciona de maravilla, pero en un archivo con funcions JavaScript para el Main intento a través de la función click (Para el CheckBox) deshabilitar el data list. Desde ahí manipulo un input type text que lo tengo también en PHP y funciona perfectamente desactivarlo, lo que no logro es que lo haga para ambos, pego código completo:

```
$("#chkNewProspect").click(function()
    {
        var checked_status = this.checked;

        if (checked_status == true)
        {
            $("#txtNewProspect").removeAttr("disabled");
            document.getElementById("dlClient").disabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#txtNewProspect").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            // document.getElementById("#dlClient").disabled = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: cuanto te refieres al data list es el : <input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">....

Comment: Gracias: en el cuerpo de la pagina en PHP tengo creado el datalist de la siguiente manera: <input list="dlClient" class='col-lg-12' style='height:35px' enabled>
<?php datalistCliente("dlClient",1,2); ?>

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoAlcocerJuárez el código va en tu pregunta dale editar y pégalo ahi, no en la zona de comentarios

Comment: otra pregunta es deseas desabilitar todo el datalist o tan solo ciertas opciones

Comment: Gracias Diego, todo el data list, como si le colocara el atributo disbled pero no logro hacerlo desde la función de JavaScript